# How to remove active class by mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've made two box which background will be changed at hover and active state. Here is my work:
http://jsfiddle.net/3Vbz8/

At there, when I click "one" it'll set to it's active state(Green Background). That's fine. When I click "Two", it'll set to active state and "one" will return to it's previous state(Grey Background). That's also fine to me.

But, I want when "one" is set to active state, at that time, if I click on "One", it'll return back to it's normal state(grey background) too. Similar event should be happen for "Two" too. How can I make this?

My applied script:

```
$('.toggle').click(function(){
   $('.toggle').removeClass("active");
   $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

**...........UPDATE...........**

Krishna helped me with this: http://jsfiddle.net/3Vbz8/1/

```
$('.toggle').click(function(){
   $('.toggle').not(this).removeClass("active");
   $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

I've noticed a issue which should be updated for my project. That issue is: if "one" is on "active" state, at that time, if any user click on "One", it'll return back to it's original state. But, if user don't remove his/her mouse pointer from that button, that button seemed on green background too. That's for hover color. So, if any user click again and again on a button he/she won't understand that's state is changed or not unless he/she moved his/her pointer.

so, I need(when mouse pointer isn't moving by user): if anyone click on "One" button, it turn's into "Green background". If user click on "One" again, it'll turn to "Grey Background" (for understanding that change user don't have to move his/her mouse pointer). In short hover color should be inactive if user click on a button again and again without moving his/her mouse pointer

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3Vbz8/8/ Krishna's answer with just a slightly different CSS approach.

Comment: The hovering effects should be like in *real world* for a better UX. I.e: let's say we have a real button that lights is we push it, by just hovering the button it usually doesn't *turn on*, rather it changes opacity or just a color level. You should keep the same methodology while creating *interactive web buttons*. Than once you click it ... make it shine!

Comment: Yes, you're right with that UX perspective. But, I haven't that button actually at my real project. I've a tick sign, a cross sign, a edit sign at my real project. At first, those are like inactive state(by inactive grey color in real world). When user click on that sign, it'll turn to active state. By hovering on them, A message to sent to them that you can only make it's active by clicking it. That's why, hover and active color is same

Comment: That's exactly my point. If you keep the hover and click state the same color you'll fall into a pitfall of users double-clicking the button making just a bad experience. My point is that by just ie: on hover to make it just slightly change a color level. You cannot go dab with it. In any case mobile users will almost not see the hover state, only if tap-holding the button :) Users know that after tapping a button they can drag the finger away in order to not activate a button, but if you light that button up... you'll just scare your users :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `not(this)` [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/not/)

http://jsfiddle.net/3Vbz8/1/

```
$('.toggle').click(function(){
   $('.toggle').not(this).removeClass("active");
   $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Edit:

I liked @Roko C.Buljan's touch to the CSS to differentiate hover vs click(in comments)

http://jsfiddle.net/3Vbz8/8

```
.toggle:hover {
    background: #888;
}

.toggle.active{
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: This is good, But when "One" is on active state, at that time, if I click "One", it'll return to it's previous state. but if I don't remove my mouse pointer from "One", it seems to green after removing "active" class too. That's because for hover color. So, the problem is: if a normal user click again and again at the "One" button, he won't understand will that set to inactive or not unless he/she won't remove his/her mouse pointer from that button.

Comment: so, how can I remove hover color when "active" remove and mouse pointer is on that button still then

Comment: @user1896653 for a better UI (User Interface) you should use a slightly different color tone for the hover state

Comment: @user1896653 - I agree with Roko C. Buljan.. you have to use a slightly lighter color to indicate hover.

Comment: Umm, using slightly different color tone on hover state won't working for me great probably. Because, I've 5-6 boxes with completely different color. And hover color and active color should be same on that. So, it'll be great for me if it can be handle with jquery function

Comment: @user1896653 listen to our advices (we're very experienced in that kind of stuff) don't use hover state color the same as your ACTIVE color! :) I might add more to my suggestion, but what I don't get is: you have more gray colors or hover-active colors? I mean are you buttons all gray by default?

Comment: Yes, my buttons are grey by default. Tick button turns to green state(hover and active), Cross button turns to red state(hover and active). Other buttons will changed too with their relevant color. In this circumstances, should I use different hover color for those?

Comment: This is good. But at my project, If I have to go with this(change hover color) at last, then I prefer your previous solution. At your this comment, hover color is near to active color. At your previous solution, hover color is near to normal color. I prefer previous because if user click on a active state button and don't move mouse pointer, he/she may be confused what's going on to see a color near active color at the time of deselected. If that color is near normal state, user can be able to understand that it's return back to it's normal state.